# I need to check perform some operations on cron output before sending the mail?

Tags: postfix, bash, cron

```
00 14 * * * /usr/local/bin/curator --dry-run --config /home/itadmin/.curator/curator.yml /home/itadmin/.curator/snapshot.yml 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee -a /home/itadmin/.curator/logs.txt | if [[ $(wc -l <logs.txt) -ge 1 ]]; then mail -s 'Status' xyz@.com fi
```

By above script i can do the all three scenarios as i mentioned above but i am getting an error like this:

```
 Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

How can i avoid this error? Any suggestions on my script?

Thanks

Comment: @RandomNotRandom's answer will solve this issue, but you could have avoided this in the first place by writing this into a script file respecting the bash coding style instead of this unreadable one-liner.

Comment: Can you pls share the example of bash coding style of script on my scenarios?

Comment: This is Google code style guide for bash:
https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a `;` in front of the `fi`.  Otherwise `bash` doesn't know that `fi` isn't part of the mail command. Right now, `bash` thinks that `fi` is part of the mail command, thus the error message.